# Maintain text position in RichTextBox while adding and removing text to the end and beginning respectively

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0

I have a very simple form with a `RichTextBox` field.  It is acting as a crude log file viewer.  As log data is added to the file I append the new data to the text box.  This works great but I wanted to prevent the text box from scrolling when the new data was appended so the currently visible data could be read.  I experimented with this for a while and I ultimately had to call the native `SendEvent` function to get and set the scroll position before and after appending the text.  This has also been working great, however, I now have a new problem: over time the log file can grow quite large and use huge amounts of memory to keep the entire contents of the log file in the text box.  So now what I've done is limited the amount of text in the text box by removing text from the beginning if the text size reaches a certain threshold.

So now my problem is that I can maintain the scroll position, but the text will change since I am removing text from the beginning.  Is there a simple way to change the scroll position to maintain readability (obviously if the user is reading the first line of the text box and that is removed then there is nothing that can be done, but I think that is acceptable)?

Here's an example: say my threshold is 1MB of text in the text box.  If there is currently 1MB of text, and I need to append 1000 characters then I also need to remove 1000 characters from the beginning.  If I am scrolled to the middle of the text then I can maintain that scroll position after the removal and appending of text but now the text that I was reading is further up.

Maybe I need to rethink my approach?

Comment: If you know you're removing **n** characters from the beginning, can't you simply move the carat back **n** characters (or to position 0, if the result is negative)?

Comment: That's a good suggestion but the caret doesn't move with the scroll position.  And even if it did, that could interfere with text selections.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that modifying the text while the user is viewing it doesn't really make sense.  So I decided to add an option to this form to 'freeze' updates to the text box.  When frozen no text will be appended or removed and the user can freely scroll around.  When unfrozen all of the appending/removing works as normal.